# Solving Recursion issues with Symfony and JsonSerializable

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I'm looking for some input on recursion issues in doctrine entities using Symfony. A lot of the time we are running into this problem when we use JsonSerializable.

It makes total sense why this happens but it's extremely annoying when you're using a lot of related entities that needs to be serialized.

I know there are other libraries for seralizing with depth monitoring, but those aren't quite as convenient as JsonSerializable; especially when an entire project is already built this way.

Is there any way to limit the depth with JsonSeralizable?

Comment: I've been running into the same issue. It's quite vexing, especially considering that most of the doctrine relations are very basic, and never used to be an issue in previous versions. I'd be interested to see how others solve this in an elegant manner.